# Python paramiko ssh channel send() does not work occasionally

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am running python 2.6.6 (64 bit) on windows 7 with paramiko version 1.12.0.

I have a script that runs an executable on a remote unix machine. The script works most of the time (50-70%) but doesn't work occasionally . Here is a simplified version of my script.

```
import paramiko
import logging
logger = paramiko.util.logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, 22, username, password)

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()

chan.send("cd /home/usr/exe_loc\n")
buff = _read_buffer(chan)
print(buff)

send_code = chan.send("nohup exe_name -r1234 &\n")

print("exec exit code = %d"%send_code)
```

_read_buffer prints buffer and works as expected.

Even when the script fails to run the executable, the 'cd' command is still printed by the buffer and the send_code is > 0 meaning the command was sent successfully(?).

I compared 'filename.log' file generated by successful run, failed run. The only difference is the failed run has an additional line (below) at the end of the file.

```
DEB [20160212-16:04:31.512] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

Also, this happens more frequently when I run the script after a long break. When I run this back to back for debugging it rarely fails.

Any ideas on why this could be going on here? Let me know if I can provide additional information.

Comment: You aren't waiting for responses so it may be that the client script closes the channel too early. I think you'd be better off with `ssh.exec_command("cd /home/usr/exe_loc;nohup exe_name -r1234 &\n")` and let paramiko sweat the details.

Comment: In my application, I use send() at several other places. How do I wait for responses? I would prefer this over exec_command() if possible.

Comment: As a minum use `sendall` or risk missing data. You'd need to read the channel and look for something like the shell prompt (which varies by remote account). `send` isn't more efficient... its just harder. You can run many `exec_command` 's and that's the normal way to do things.